# How to apply aggregate functions to numpy matrices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to pass a function which returns binary integers given an array (row) and apply to a matrix.

Row input -> [1,1,1]; desired output -> 1

```py
def gen_y(X):
  if np.sum(X) > 2:
    return 1 
  elif np.sum(X) < 2:
    return 0 
  else:
    return int(np.random.uniform(0,1) > 0.5)
```

The input is of shape (100,3) where there are 3 columns and this function should be applied to each row; thus the output should be of shape (100,1).

The apply_along_axis function should be applicable.

```py
np_gen_y = np.vectorize(gen_y)
y = np.apply_along_axis(np_gen_y, 0, X)
```

However, the input and output are as follows

```
#Input
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       ...
       ])
#Output
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       ...
       ])
```

How should the numpy function be modified to return the desired effect?

```
#desired output
array([[1],
       [0],
       [0],
       ...
       ])
```

Edit: I've found that if I remove the vectorized definition `np_gen_y` and just use `y = np.apply_along_axis(gen_y, 1, X)` this works; but I'd like to know why vectorization is not appropriate?

Comment: It's not clear why you are are using `vectorize` rather than just passing the function to `apply_along_axis()` like `np.apply_along_axis(gen_y, 0, X)`

Answer (score 0):

Your function - without the `random` which confuses testing:

```
In [148]: def gen_y(X):
     ...:   if np.sum(X) > 2:
     ...:     return 1 
     ...:   elif np.sum(X) < 2:
     ...:     return 0 
     ...:   else:
     ...:     return 2 # random is not good for testing
     ...:     

In [149]: arr = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
     ...:        [1, 1, 0],
     ...:        [0, 1, 0],
     ...:        ])
```

Using `apply`:

```
In [150]: np.apply_along_axis(gen_y, 0, arr)
Out[150]: array([2, 1, 0])
```

Which for a 2d array is not an improvement over:

```
In [151]: np.array([gen_y(x) for x in arr.T])
Out[151]: array([2, 1, 0])
```

`apply_along` can make nest iterations on 3d arrays prettier, but I have yet to find a case where it is faster.

But we can take the sums with:

```
In [152]: arr.sum(axis=0)
Out[152]: array([2, 3, 1])
```

and apply a bit of masking to change the values to 1/0/2. This will be faster.

To see what `vectorize` does, modify your function to see what it gets:

```
In [155]: def foo(X):
     ...:     print(X)
     ...:     return gen_y(X)
     ...:     

In [156]: np.vectorize(foo)(arr)
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
1
0
Out[156]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

`vectorize` passes scalar values to the function - while `apply_along` passes 1d arrays.  You wrote your function for 1d arrays, not scalar values.

Did you reread the `vectorize` docs after you got confusing results?

`vectorize` has a `signature` option that lets us pass arrays:

```
In [161]: np.vectorize(foo, signature="(n)->()")(arr.T)
[1 1 0]
[1 1 1]
[1 0 0]
Out[161]: array([2, 1, 0])
```

Some times:

```
In [165]: timeit np.vectorize(gen_y, signature="(n)->()")(arr.T)
212 µs ± 482 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [166]: timeit np.apply_along_axis(gen_y, 0, arr)
141 µs ± 5.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [167]: timeit np.array([gen_y(x) for x in arr.T])
65.5 µs ± 2.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

`vectorize` has a performance disclaimer (did you read it?), and with `signature` it's even worse.  The list comprehension usually is faster, though for some large arrays `np.vectorize` (without signature) does relatively well.